Dropdown Not Displaying & Scrollable Table Issues in Angular with Flowbite
I’m working on an Angular project using Flowbite, and I’m encountering two main issues:

The dropdown menu for actions (with options like "Modifier" "Consulter" "Clôturer") doesn't display when clicked. I believe the issue might be related to CSS classes, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
I want to make my table scrollable both vertically and horizontally.

I’ve tried various approaches to solve these problems but haven’t had any success so far. I was expecting the dropdown to appear when the button was clicked, and for the table to be scrollable both vertically and horizontally.
Here's the relevant code and a screenshot of the issue:
<div class="rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white p-4 shadow-sm sm:p-6">
  <div class="items-center justify-between lg:flex">
    <div class="mb-4 lg:mb-0">
      <span class="text-sm font-normal text-gray-500"
        >Choisissez le(s) actions que vous souhaitez compléter:</span
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-6 flex flex-col">
    <div class="overflow-x-auto">
      <div class="inline-block min-w-full align-middle">
        <div class="overflow-hidden shadow">
          <table
            class="min-w-full table-fixed border-collapse border border-gray-200"
          >
            <thead class="bg-gray-50">
              <tr>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-white border-r-gray-200 bg-white text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                ></th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Nom de l'action
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Date début
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Date fin
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Date de réalisation
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Responsable
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Livrable
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  État
                </th>
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                >
                  Observation
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="border border-white bg-white p-2"></th>
                <th scope="col" class="border border-white bg-white"></th>
                <!-- <th
                  scope="col"
                  class="p-4 text-left text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-500"
                ></th> -->
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-white">
              <tr *ngFor="let action of actions; let i = index">
                <td class="border border-white border-r-gray-200 pr-2">
                  <button
                    id="dropdownComment1Button"
                    data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownComment1"
                    class="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg bg-white p-2 text-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-50"
                    type="button"
                  >
                    <svg
                      class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-500"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                      <path
                        d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                  <!-- Dropdown menu -->
                  <div
                    id="dropdownComment1"
                    class="z-50 hidden w-36 divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded bg-white shadow"
                  >
                    <ul
                      class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700"
                      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuIconHorizontalButton"
                    >
                      <li>
                        <a class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100"
                          >Modifier</a
                        >
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100"
                          >Consulter</a
                        >
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100"
                          >Clôturer</a
                        >
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td
                  class="max-w-xs overflow-hidden truncate border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-white"
                >
                  {{ action.name }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  {{ action.startDate | date: "shortDate" }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-white"
                >
                  {{ action.endDate | date: "shortDate" }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  {{ action.realizationDate | date: "shortDate" }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  {{ action.responsible }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  {{ action.deliverable }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  <span *ngIf="action.progressStatus > 0">
                    {{ action.progressStatus / 100 | percent: "1.0-0" }}
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-gray-200 p-4 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                >
                  {{ action.observation }}
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-white pl-2 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500"
                >
                  <div>
                    <svg
                      *ngIf="
                        action.attachments && action.attachments.length > 0
                      "
                      class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-500"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      width="24"
                      height="24"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    >
                      <path
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"
                        stroke-width="2"
                        d="M7 8v8a5 5 0 1 0 10 0V6.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V15a2 2 0 0 0 4 0V8"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td
                  class="border border-white pl-2 text-sm font-normal text-gray-500"
                >
                  <div
                    [ngClass]="{
                      'h-4 w-4 rounded-full': true,
                      'bg-primary-700': action.progressStatus == 100,
                      'bg-warning-500':
                        action.progressStatus >= 50 &&
                        action.progressStatus < 100,
                      'bg-red-600': action.progressStatus < 50
                    }"
                  ></div>
                </td>
                <!-- <td class="border border-gray-200 p-4">
                  <div class="flex">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      (click)="openEditActionModal(action)"
                      class="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg px-1 py-1 text-center text-sm font-medium text-primary-700 focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      <svg
                        class="h-4 w-4"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M17.414 2.586a2 2 0 00-2.828 0L7 10.172V13h2.828l7.586-7.586a2 2 0 000-2.828z"
                        ></path>
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h4a1 1 0 010 2H4v10h10v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      (click)="openActionDetailsModal(action)"
                      class="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-center text-sm font-medium text-warning-800 focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      <svg
                        class="h-4 w-4"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M4.998 7.78C6.729 6.345 9.198 5 12 5c2.802 0 5.27 1.345 7.002 2.78a12.713 12.713 0 0 1 2.096 2.183c.253.344.465.682.618.997.14.286.284.658.284 1.04s-.145.754-.284 1.04a6.6 6.6 0 0 1-.618.997 12.712 12.712 0 0 1-2.096 2.183C17.271 17.655 14.802 19 12 19c-2.802 0-5.27-1.345-7.002-2.78a12.712 12.712 0 0 1-2.096-2.183 6.6 6.6 0 0 1-.618-.997C2.144 12.754 2 12.382 2 12s.145-.754.284-1.04c.153-.315.365-.653.618-.997A12.714 12.714 0 0 1 4.998 7.78ZM12 15a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6Z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </td> -->
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Screenshot of the dropdown issue
Any advice on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
